# failed to parse csv specific date format into date in logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I have date field like this `1994/Jan`  In CSV .How to change it into date format.

What i am trying is this :

```
filter {mutate{convert=>["field_name","date"]}}
```

But its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
    filter{
      date{
        match => [ "field_source","yyyy/MMM"]
        target =>  "field_target"
      }
}
```